# What is the difference between 'dimension', 'dimensional' and 'dimensionality'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, synonyms

Could someone show me the difference?  I do not know how to distinguish the usage of *dimension* and *dimensionality* when saying something is high-*dimensional*.

Answer (score 9):

*[Dimension](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dimension)* is a noun.

> A measurable **extent** of a particular kind, such as *length*, *breadth*,
>   *depth*, or *height*:
>
> *Length is a **dimension** in this system.*

Transforming a noun into an adjective with -[al](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-al) denotes *relating to* or *kind of*:

> The noun *dimension* + -*al* produces the adjective *dimensional*:
>
> ***relating*** to dimension.
>
> *The Y axis is a **dimensional** reference for length in the system.*

Forming a noun with -[ity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-ity) denotes a *quality* or *condition*:

> The adjective *dimensional* + -*ity* produces the noun *dimensionality*:
>
> the ***condition*** of relating to dimension.
>
> *An additional axis changes the **dimensionality** in the system.*

1. The noun *dimension* refers to the actual **thing**.
2. The adjective *dimensional* refers to **relating** to the actual thing.
3. The noun *dimensionality* refers to the **condition** of relating to the actual thing.

Answer (score 3):

Changing what is up or down into what is left or right is a change in dimension: the vertical dimension is changed to the horizontal dimension.  Changing what can be drawn on a sheet of paper to what needs also height above the paper to be properly displayed is a change in dimensionality: two dimensions is changed to 3D, with 3 spatial dimensions.  A higher order dimensionality requires additional information to specify the locations of things.

Answer (score -1):

**"Dimension"** refers to actual, three-dimensional measurements, and **"dimensionality"** refers to perceived dimensions, represented two-dimensionally. For example: *dimensionality* within a pattern printed on fabric. (Actually, you could use "dimension" for both descriptions, but "dimensionality" implies that it is an illusion.

Comment: None of this is particularly helpful since the definitions of the "dimension" words consist of dimension words.  "Dimensionality" does not imply illusion although the *projection* or *depiction* of a higher dimension in a lower one may involve optical illusions.  A discussion of these words should involve both the mathematical and the vernacular.  FYI, I am not the downvoter.